# Java - Create a variable which does the same thing as a name of a class

Tags: java, class, variables, reflection

Maybe the title souds misterious, but i don't the specific words of java.
I will try to be clear :

I would like to create an instance of the class `A<T extends B>`, but I only know the Type of T.

```
Type myType = ...; //defined in my code via getGenericParameterTypes() from a Constructor object
Class myVariable = Class.forName(myType.getTypeName());
A<myVariable> = new A<myVariable>(); //doesn't work
```

Maybe some of you may know a solution or an other way to do it.

Thank you !

EDIT :
Here is more information :

I have a class `A<T extends B>` and i have to call it recursively, the only parameter is T and T is the class of a parameter of a method.
I got the name of T using :

```
Type typeT = cl.getConstructors()[0].getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
String nameT = typeT.getTypeName();
```

now i want to do

```
A<T> myNewInstance = new A<T>();
```

But i dont know how to define T

Comment: you mean something like getClass() ?

Comment: The thing is: any variable must have a known **type**. You can have variables that come with unknown type parameters (for generics); but the type itself can't be "unknown". Maybe you better step back and tell us what kind of problem you want to solve using this approach.